# How do I remove Ubuntu from a dual-boot Windows 7 laptop?

Tags: partitioning, uninstall

I'm new to Ubuntu and liked it a lot! However after testing it on my old crappy laptop I now want to remove it. I've looked at tutorials on how to uninstall and it says to start by deleting the Linux partition of the hard drive.

However after opening Computer management, I cannot locate my Linux partition. Same as when I go to System Configuration and click on the "boot" tab, my computer does not list any operating system other than Windows 7. Any way around this or perhaps a different way to uninstall?

Answer (score 3):

### Step 1

Boot from a Ubuntu Live CD.

### Step 2

Open Terminal.

### Step 3

Run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/os-uninstaller
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install -y os-uninstaller && os-uninstaller
```

### Step 4

Select the OS you wish to uninstall, in this case Ubuntu.

### Step 5

Reboot and enjoy your Ubuntu-free system.

*Source: [Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller)*

Comment: The only operating system that provides an easy application to uninstall.  haha thats funny.  Thanks for posting this.

Comment: will a memory stick work like a live cd? sorry not very good with computers.

Comment: Yes, it will. You can use [LiLi](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) to create a bootable USB key using the Ubuntu ISO.

Comment: I have created a Live CD and booted my pc from it, do i click on "try ubuntu without installing it" to get to terminal?

Comment: Yes. Once the Live session is loaded, simply click on the Ubuntu logo in the top left corner of the screen and start typing `terminal`. The app's shortcut will appear and you'll be able to click on it to launch it.

Comment: I'm having a bit of a problem, the OS uninstaller freezes while searching for my os (os probe). or maybe I'm not giving it enough time, should it take more than 4 hours to find my os on a pc with 4 gigs of ram?

Comment: @SirCharlo Does this work inside Ubuntu?

Comment: I believe it does!

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't see linux because it doesn't have drivers to view those partitions.

If you want to delete those partitions try using the same cd except booting into the Live Environment.

Then it is as simple as using the disk utility.  Make sure you don't accidentally delete your windows partition.